# Turn String to JSX - curly brackets issue

Tags: html, reactjs, string, parsing, jsx

I'm receiving string from backend:

```
     "<img src={props.url} className="image"></img>"
```

And on React frontend I need to turn it into React component. I'm using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it gives me this in HTML:

```
<img src="{props.url}" class="image">
```

So the problem is: `src="{props.url}"` - src attribute is converted to string instead of inline Javascript so my image will not load.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: hey did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around for this, and it does not involve any external libraries. Valid jsx can be stored in arrays as shown:

```
const html = [<img src={img} className="image"></img>]
return <div>{ html }</div>
```

If you store the html in an array, it can be rendered very simply.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work either. I guess ReactHtmlParser is just wrapper around dangerouslySetInnerHTML so they do quite the same thing.

Comment: Yes I just realized that. Sorry

Comment: @Mr.Pear I posted another potential solution

Comment: thanks for help, although you are right - you can store jsx in an array, I can't have that array from backend - my data is coming as JSON String. I need to find a way to turn String to JSX on frontend side, and the only problem is curly brackets syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, though there might be a better approach, this does do your job -

```
const imageVar = <img src="{props.url}" class="image"> //after using dangerouslySetInnerHTML

cont imageSrc = eval(imageVar.props.src.replace(/['{}]+/g, ""));

return(<img src={srcvar} class={imageVar.props.class} />);
```

Working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-snowflake-kr3xp?file=/src/App.js)

Hope this helps you. :)